# Automation of test suite generation in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, automation

I would like to automate test suite generation in eclipse which includes following steps in manual process.
can anyone help me how to achive this using java or any other comfortable language.

Right click on package -> select 'New' -> 'other'

click on 'test' ->select 'TPTP junit test'  -> click on 'next'

give package and Test name -> click Finish

Add testcases in  'Test methods' tab

complete invocation in 'behavior' tab

save and close.

Tool should ask Test name and number of test cases needs to be generated and with this info test suite should be generated.

[Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utldL.png)
[Step 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRPgs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just try [MoreUnit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/). I didn't find how to add test cases with it, but it can handle the most part of the steps you've described.